# IdentityServer4 + OWIN client: logout request not sending cookies to external IdP (because it is xhr)

Tags: cookies, owin, identityserver4, adfs

## The setup

I have an identity provider based on IdentityServer4 with AD FS as an external identity provider.

I have 3 different types of clients:

1. a production hybrid flow client based on OWIN lib
2. a test hybrid flow client (the latest sample client from the IdentityServer4 repo)
3. implicit flow clients (Angular)

## The problem

The test client and the implicit flow clients work as expected.
When logging out from the OWIN client, the user is logged out from my IdP, but not from AD FS.

## Some analysis

When logging out from the OWIN client, cookies are not sent when logging out from AD FS. In consequence, AD FS does not delete any cookies and thus the user stays logged in at the AD FS.

The ultimate reason is that the corresponding request is an xhr request which cannot send cookies (see also [SAML logout request is not sending cookies to IdP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010554/saml-logout-request-is-not-sending-cookies-to-idp), although we don't use SAML).

To summarize here are the calls you can observe in the browser:

1. **Request** GET https://myidp/connect/endsession
   **Query Parameters** post_logout_redirect_uri=https://xxx, id_token_hint=xxx, x-client-SKU=ID_NET45, x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
   **Response** Redirect to https://myidp/account/logout?logoutId=xxx
2. **Request** GET  https://myidp/account/logout
   **Query Parameters** logoutId=xxx
   **Response** Redirect to https://myadfs/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=xxx&id_token_hint=xxx&state=xxx&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
3. **Request** GET https://myadfs/oauth2/logout
   **Request type** xhr
   **Query parameters** post_logout_redirect_uri=xxx, id_token_hint=xxx, state=xxx, x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0, x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
   **Response** Ok

For the OWIN client, the last call is of type xhr, for the other clients, it is of type document. I think something in the initial call from the client to myidp must be different such hat the redirect chain ends in a xhr request. What is this something? How can I change this behaviour?

I checked to headers of each call meticulously. Most suspect to me look the Sec-Fetch-Headers (the rest is pretty much equal for all clients), but I don't understand what they actually do.

For the OWIN client:

```
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

For the other clients:

```
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
```

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: Looks like a SameSite cookie or CORS issue?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I don't believe in a CORS issue. I had one (only for the OWIN client!) and resolved it by configuring AD FS for setting CORS headers.
But can you elaborate further on the SameSite cookie issue? What could happen? What is the root cause for different behaviour for different clients and how can I change it?

Comment: The recent SameSite changes in the browsers will if not properly configured result in that cookies are not included when you do cross-domain requests. Not sure if this is related to your issue though.

Answer (score 0):

The [post I cited above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010554/saml-logout-request-is-not-sending-cookies-to-idp) actually was perfectly right: We have to interrupt the chain of xhr redirects and do a normal browser redirect instead.

However, we needed some time to figure out how to achieve this. Here is our solution:

The Logout action in our AuthorizationController returned Redirect, we had to replace it by a Ok response. This means replace

```
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
      Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
      // ...Code for clearing cookies...
      return Redirect("/myroute");
    }    
}
```

by

```
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
      Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
      // ...Code for clearing cookies...
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```